# Letsencrypt nginx, renew returns a 404

Tags: nginx, lets-encrypt, certbot

I'm having a issue with letsencrypt certificate renewal.
Why I run `certbot renew --dry-run`, then the renew fails with the site
returning a 404.

See my nginx config below (jinja temlate). The `{{ ssl_challenge_dir }}`
variable is the same one used for `--webroot-path` when I originally generated
the certificates.

If I place the a file with dummy content in `{{ ssl_challenge_dir
}}/.well-known/acme-challenge/test.html`, then that file is served perfectly
without raising a 404.

So I'm a bit perplexed. As far as I understand when certbot runs, it creates a
temporary file under that same directory, and then tries to request it. But it
keeps returning 404.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

```
server_tokens off;
more_set_headers 'Server: ';

# Letsencrypt and SSL Redirect
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name {{ site.domain }} {{ site.name }};

    # Letsencrypt challange
    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root {{ site.ssl_challenge_dir }};
        allow all;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # Redirect all other requests to https
    location / {
        return 301 https://{{ site.name }}$request_uri;
        rewrite ^/(.*) https://{{ site.name }}/$1 permanent;
    }
}

server {
    server_name {{ site.name }};
    listen 443;
    access_log  {{ user.logs_dir }}/nginx_access.log;
    error_log {{ user.logs_dir }}/nginx_error.log;

    client_max_body_size 10M;
    gzip on;
    gzip_types text/plain image/png image/jpg;

    ssl on;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/{{ site.name }}/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/{{ site.name }}/privkey.pem;

    # Resources
    location ^~ /media/ {
        root {{ webapp.resources_dir }};
        expires 31d;
        gzip_static on;
    }

    location ^~ /static/ {
        root {{ webapp.resources_dir }};
        expires 0;
        gzip_static on;
    }

    location / {
        {% if site.auth_required %}
        auth_basic "Restricted";
        auth_basic_user_file {{ user.home_dir }}/.htpasswd;
        {% endif %}

        proxy_pass http://unix:{{ webapp.socket }}:;
        # proxy_pass_header Server;

        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;

        proxy_connect_timeout 600;
        proxy_send_timeout 600;
        proxy_read_timeout 600;
        send_timeout 600;

        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Protocol ssl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I discovered what I was doing wrong. No issues with my nginx config.

My issue was that I used `--webroot` when running certbot to get the original certs, and basically just didn't realize that the renew command also needs to be run with `--webroot`

Comment: Found this and had the same problem with a similar set up in Apache. To be clear, you need to specify webroot options as in: ``certbot renew --webroot -w /path/to/www -d domain`` (or leave the domain off for all certs acquired using webroot method).